# ReacJS destruct function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I learnig reactjs (I'm from Angular, C#) and I broking my head with this....have this lib

```
const libA=()=>{
  const fnA = () => {
     return ...
  }
  const fnB = () => {
     return ...
  }
  const fnC = () => {
     return ...
  }

  return [fnA, fnB, fbC]
}

export default libA
```

And I consume libA this way

```
import { libA } from '../myLib.js'


const compB=()=>{
  const [fnA, fnB, fnC] = myLib()
  ....
  fnA()...

}
```

My problem is if I change order const [fnB, fnA, fnC ] is seted fns to wrong name  (fnB=fnA,...). There is any that I can getr corretly fn only by name or I need put correctly name var order? My pain is if I have 10 fns I wiil need declare all vars since I use only 1, 2, or alterante vars from lib?

basically i want same thing like old way

```
 function myLib(){
  fnA: function () {return...},
  fnB: function () {return...},
  fnC: function () {return...},
}

myLib().fnA().....

thks
```

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you exported `libA` as a `default export` so you should not import them as `named imports`

Eg: `import libA from '../myLib.js'` instead of `import { libA } from '../myLib.js'`.

Secondly, deconstructing arrays in JS mean that sequence/order of the array items are maintained. You cannot just change the order of elements when destructuring an array.

If you want to change the order of callbacks, you should export an `object` instead of an `array` in `myLib.js`

```
const libA=()=>{
  const fnA = () => {
     return ...
  }
  const fnB = () => {
     return ...
  }
  const fnC = () => {
     return ...
  }

  return {fnA, fnB, fbC}
}

export default libA
```

And you consume the `libA` like

```
const compB=()=>{
  const {fnA, fnB, fnC} = myLib()
  ....
  fnA()...

}
```

PS: you have 10, 20 or more functions in that export.

You don't need to destructure the import, simply call them by `.`

```
import libA from '../myLib.js'
const compB=()=>{
   ....
   libA()?.fnA() // conditionally call the fnA only if libA returns the function
    
}
```

Comment: so if I have 10 fns I need declare 10 vars in destruct..thre is another way to do this more concise/especific?

Comment: To know more about the `?` operator [link to docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to scope all these libs inside a function to make it work as a module. Instead take advantage of the module object itself:

```js
// libA.js

export const fnA = () => {
  return ...
}

export const fnB = () => {
  return ...
}

export const fnC = () => {
  return ...
}
```

and in the other file

```js
// anotherFile.js

import {fnA, fnB, fnC} from '../libA.js'

libA()
libB()
{...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other guy already mentioned that you probably not need destructure at all so direct `import` would be the best solution here.

But just in sake of completeness: if we have hook(`myLib` does not look as a hook, but let's assume) and it returns array and we don't want to put every array's item into separate variable - say, because we don't use them all, we have two alternatives.

First, we can just avoid destructuring:

```
myLibCallbacks = useMyLib();
...
myLibCallbacks[4]('a', 1, 2);
```

Sure, does not look good with this numeric indexes. Alternative is skipping elements [during destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
const [fnA,,,,fnE] = useMyLib();
```

Sure, if we can change `useMyLib` return value to be an object instead of array - we definitely should do that.

Comment: yes, tks for response. I'm thinking in create services with less (more especifics) methods....I was going to way that lib need all methods for your domain (login, payments, ..) but now I guess is better create "mini-services" with your specifics methods. Like Toni said